# error for - if : The results are not as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, if-statement

I don't get the values that I should get - You can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhvnwz

```
countStateStudents(){
  for (let student of this.students){
if (student.state == 1){
  this.signedup++;
} else
if (student.state == 2){
  this.boughtPIN++;
} else
if (student.state == 3){
  this.enrolled++;
} else
if (student.state == 4){
  this.notinterested++;
}
 }
```

Comment: as @Nikhil wrote, also u could use here switch instead those if & else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting unexpected values because you are calling `countStateStudents()` multiple times. And the values are incremented every time you call the method.

Instead, you should just call the method once, and access the values returned  without calling it again.

**Component:**

```
ngOnInit() {    

    const status = this.studentService.countStateStudents();

    this.signedup = status.incritos;
    this.boughtPIN = status.compropin;
    this.enrolled = status.matriculado;
    this.notinterested = status.nointeresado;
}
```